# Constructing a SQL save, update, remove query from hibernate entities?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to create native SQL-queries for saving, updating or removing certain entities from the database via hibernate ?

What i am searching for is pretty much this...

```
String sqlQuery = session.save(listOfEntities);
session.execute(sqlQuery);

sqlQuery : "insert into players(id,...) values((10,...),(11,...))"
```

Comment: you can enable debug logs for hibernate.sql package and the queries will be visible in logs.

Comment: @AvinashSagar And if i need them during runtime ?

Comment: Do you mean that you need the sql queries to be read by your code somewhere before execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need the statements? Just doing `session.persist(entity)` will execute the statement for you already.